# Use google calendar to check for holidays

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to figure out how to validate a specific date (lets say Today) against google calendar, i need to build a function that checks whether today is a holiday or not.

I can see the actual calender at https://www.google.com/calendar/htmlembed?src=thai@holiday.calendar.google.com
But i want to figure out a way to check specific dates for events by API

i would be more then happy if someone could point me out to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you'll need your calendar address which you find like this: https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37103?hl=en

Then load the calendar entries into an array:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("path/to/calendar");
$xml->asXML();
$holidays = array();
foreach ($xml->entry as $entry){
  $a = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
  $when = $a->when->attributes()->startTime;

  $holidays[(string)$when]["title"] = $entry->title;
}
```

Now check if a date exists in your calendar

```
if(is_array($holidays[date("Y-m-d")]))
    echo "holiday";
else 
    echo "Not holiday";
```

You can add parameters to your URL to be more specific.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/reference#Parameters